# Special characters in URL - need to get the capital Ø

Tags: javascript, regex, utf-8

I have the following URL:

```
my.site/?param1=Økonomi&param2=Penger
```

I'm using this function to get the parameters value:

```
function getQueryStringValue(url, key) {
    var params = {};
    var url_params = url.split("?", 2);

    if (url_params.length > 1) {
        var param_list = url_params[1].split("&");
        param_list.map(function (param_str) {
            var kv = param_str.split("=", 2);
            params[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        });
    }
    return (key in params)? decodeURIComponent(params[key]) : ''
}
```

When logging the results, these are the values returned:
`param1 = %C3%98konomi` and `param2 = Penger`

When querying this against my dataset, I cannot get a match of the results named `Økonomi` with a capital `Ø`. If I change the data to `økonomi`, I get a match.

So does the encoded URI value `%C3%98` not return `Ø`? How can I make sure it will?

Comment: What does `console.log(url)` show in `getQueryStringValue`? `decodeURIComponent('%C3%98')` definitely should be `'Ø'`.

Comment: Your entire URL is `%C3%98`? Interesting. How are you calling `getQueryStringValue` and checking the result?

Comment: The entire URL logs:
`param1=%C3%98konomi&param2=Penger`

I'm calling the function inside a getJSON function:
`var firma = getQueryStringValue(url, "param1");`

Comment: And you `console.log(firma);` and the result still contains `%C3%98`?

Comment: console.log(firma) gives `Økonomi`

Comment: So how are you determining that there’s a problem?

Comment: If `firma=Økonomi` I should be able to get results from a JSON search using Defiant.js.

I'm searching for keys that contains the value stored in variable `firma`.

I get the results containing `økonomi` but not `Økonomi` (small and capital letter Ø)

Comment: So this has nothing at all to do with URLs and everything to do with Defiant.js? You might want to edit your question to reflect that.

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure. I maybe mistakenly be put off that my console log gave me `%C3%98`

Comment: @torazaburo: The second parameter to `split` is equivalent to slicing the split, the URL is obviously encoded going into the function, and the line is not invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```js
const getQueryStringValue = (url, key) => 
    ((decodeURIComponent(url).split('?')[1] || '').match(new RegExp(`${key}=([^&]*)`)) || [,null])[1]

const url = encodeURIComponent('my.site/?param1=Økonomi&param2=Penger')
console.log(getQueryStringValue(url, 'param1'))
console.log(getQueryStringValue(url, 'param2'))
console.log(getQueryStringValue('my.site/', 'param2'))
console.log(getQueryStringValue('my.site/?param1=Økonomi&param2=Penger', 'param3'))
```

Browsers encode url using `encodeUriComponent` function and you have to decode it.

```js
console.log(decodeURIComponent('%C3%98'))
```